# How to get href of anchor when the event.target is HTMLImageElement?

Tags: javascript, events, anchor, href

I want to get the href of an anchor element when it is clicked.
I am using the following javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event)
{
    event = event || window.event;
    var el = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (el instanceof HTMLAnchorElement)
    {
        console.log(el.getAttribute('href'));
    }
}, true);
```

This works perfectly for an embedded anchor such as this:

```
<div><p><a href='link'></a></p><div>
```

But it doesn't work when I am working with an anchor and an image:

```
<div><a href='link'><img></a></div>
```

The `event.target` is returning the image instead of the anchor.
The javascript code can be amended with the following `if` case to get around this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event)
{
    event = event || window.event;
    var el = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (el instanceof HTMLImageElement)
    {
        // Using parentNode to get the image element parent - the anchor element.
        console.log(el.parentNode.getAttribute('href'));
    }
    else if (el instanceof HTMLAnchorElement)
    {
        console.log(el.getAttribute('href'));
    }
}, true);
```

But this doesn't seem very elegant and I'm wondering if there is a better way.

**!IMPORTANT!**
NOTE: Keep in mind, I have no access to an ID or class, or any other traditional identifier for that matter. All I know is that there will be an anchor clicked and I need to get its href. I don't even know where it will be, if it exists or will be created later.

EDIT: Please no jQuery or other javascript libraries.

Comment: You are looking for `.currentTarget` or simply `this`, which will refer to the element the handler is installed on and not the one that was clicked.

Comment: Both `.currentTarget` and `this` are the `document` element as the event listener is used on it.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you used a global handler.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rather than adding a global `click` handler, why not just target only anchor tags?

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0, length = anchors.length; i < length; i++) {
  var anchor = anchors[i];
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // `this` refers to the anchor tag that's been clicked
    console.log(this.getAttribute('href'));
  }, true);
};
```

If you want to stick with the document-wide *click* handler then you could crawl upwards to determine if the thing clicked is-or-is-contained-within a link like so:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    while (target) {
      if (target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement) {
        console.log(target.getAttribute('href'));
        break;
      }

      target = target.parentNode;
    }
}, true);
```

This way at least you'd avoid writing brittle code that has to account for all of the possible types of anchor-children and nested structure.

Comment: Was just writing the same answer, this is the way to go.

Comment: I have thought about this but I am wondering if the amount of anchors on a page could make the loops be an unnecessary performance issue. Not to mention all the resulting javascript code. Also, as explained in my note, I don't know if the element with the anchor exists, and your solution supposes it does. There are workarounds for this but they are not pretty.

Comment: This is truly an excellent piece of code! Not quite the utopian solution I was hoping for, but it will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

Instead of looping all anchors in the DOM, lookup from the `event.target` element.
Using **JavaScript's  [.closest() <sup>*MDN Docs*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)**

```js
addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();                     // Don't navigate!
  const anchor = event.target.closest("a");   // Find closest Anchor (or self)
  if (!anchor) return;                        // Not found. Exit here.
  console.log( anchor.getAttribute('href'));  // Log to test
});
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/29223576/383904">
  <span>
      <img src="//placehold.it/200x60?text=Click+me">  
  </span>
</a>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/29223576/383904">
  Or click me
</a>
```

it basically works like jQuery's .closest() which does

> **Closest or Self** (Find closest parent... else - target me!)

better depicted in the example above.

Comment: This is a really great solution. It is more future proof and more maintainable than my solution. However, it has terrible browser support. :(

Comment: @AurelijeAure I like to push the www forward, so I expect a load of uses in the near future cause this method is a living standard yet to be adopted by all vendors.

Comment: Now that I think of it, this solution would get an href on every single click if there is an anchor present on the page, as it would proceed to parse the DOM until it finds one.

Comment: @AurelijeAure yes, cause it uses `document` - instead use `Array.from` passing `document.querySelectorAll('a')`  and add the listener to every Anchor element. To make sure it really has a `href` you can use the Attribute selector `document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')`

Comment: Really a great solution. event.target.href was giving me undefined